# Number of windows to cascade in MDI winform

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI application that I have set up with a starting window state of "Normal". When I open each new child form, it automagically opens in a cascading format. It ends up looking like this:

[image: cascade example]

This is fine for a few times, but it keeps opening lower and lower even if:

1. you close one or all of them
2. you move one or all of them
3. it runs way out of the visible space (forcing you to scroll or move it to see it).

   It will eventually reset after **11** opened instances and start opening from the top like it did originally.

I can't figure out how to change that "11" number to ... maybe... "3". How do I do that?
What is the name of this hidden property?

I fear it may be something I need .Net Reflector to even see... Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: My guess is that the code that handles this is native Windows MDI code. I doubt you'll be able to get at the internals and change it, looks like you'll have to take full control. If I ever want to understand implementation details like this I always refer to the Wine source code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to do this manually by setting the StartPosition of you child forms to Manual and setting their Location properties appropriately before when they open: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/d9e0ff9f-52a0-4836-a718-2b73bdfb9cc6